# Is it possible to set markdown to False with pymsteams?

Tags: python, markdown, microsoft-teams

How do I set markdown to False using pymsteams?

```
import pymsteams

message = pymsteams.connectorcard('<webhook>')
message.text('my text'.replace('\n', '<br>').replace('_', '\_'))
message.send()
```

I want to send a message to a channel on Microsoft Teams, but the markdown format turns any text surrounded by underscores to italic. I added a backslash before every underscore to prevent this.

I read about markdown and it seems like setting it to False will prevent the above issue. Right now, I only have underscores in some of the messages, but I'm sure later ones are going to have other symbols. Is there a way to set markdown to False with pymsteams so that I don't have to add additional `replace()` in my code?

Comment: Could you please add more details here? Are you trying to send a connector card?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending a connector card. I added more info to the original post. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the text that I want to send within `<pre>` and `</pre>` solved the issue I was having with underscore.

```
import pymsteams

message = pymsteams.connectorcard('<webhook>')

text = '_hello_'
message.text(f'<pre>\n{text}\n</pre>')
message.send()
```

The underscores, spacing, and newlines show up on the Teams channel now.